# How to make properly cross-subdomain authentication with Yii2?

Tags: php, authentication, yii2, session-cookies, yii2-basic-app

Faced with the problem. 
I've created 2 server aliases for main domain (like subdomains ***ru***.testproject.local and ***en***.testproject.local). Also made a cross-subdomain authentication, using this code in the config file of Yii2 (basic app):

```
'user' => [
  //'class' => 'yii\web\User',
  'identityClass' => 'app\models\Users',
  'enableAutoLogin' => true,
  'identityCookie' => [
    'name' => '_identity',
    'httpOnly' => true,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => '.testproject.local',
  ],
],
'session' => [
  //'savePath' => '\app\session',
  'cookieParams' => [
    'domain' => '.testproject.local',
    //'httpOnly' => true,
    //'path' => '/',
  ],
],
```

According to this one, authentication works on the main domain and subdomains as well. But I can't **Log out** on the main domain (although on the subdomains I can do this). I've tried to remove **enableAutoLogin** property. And of course it works like I need. But it's not a good solution, because when user closes his browser and opens it again, he we'll need also to Log in again. What can I do for fixing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this instead?

```
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Users',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_identity',
            'httpOnly' => true,
            'domain' => '.testproject.local',
        ],
    ],
    'session' => [
        'cookieParams' => [
            'domain' => '.testproject.local',
            'path' => '/',
            'httpOnly' => true,
            'secure' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

After you have logged in, confirm that _identity cookie domain and path is the same for both main and subdomain website through browser console.

---

**Updated**

The actual cookie that tracks current visitor session is actually the `session` config array.

The default class for session config is `yii\web\Session`.
This is the comment found in the code.

```
/**
 * @var array parameter-value pairs to override default session cookie parameters that are used for session_set_cookie_params() function
 * Array may have the following possible keys: 'lifetime', 'path', 'domain', 'secure', 'httponly'
 * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php
 */
private $_cookieParams = ['httponly' => true];
```

As for `user` config array, it is using `yii\web\User` mainly for the current visitor status whether just a guest or logged in user. Below is the comment in the code.

```
/**
 * @var array the configuration of the identity cookie. This property is used only when [[enableAutoLogin]] is true.
 * @see Cookie
 */
public $identityCookie = ['name' => '_identity', 'httpOnly' => true];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really works now. But could you explain, what the problem was with my code? As I've seen, you don't use "path" parameter for cookie settings (although uses this one for session). And, as a result, everything works fine. But why does it happen? Thanks in advance

Comment: I found that this worked when I added the cookie 'name' under cookieParams. Has to be the same for all subdomains.